# Huge whitespace appearing when converting .png to .gif with bash convert

Tags: bash, png, gif, imagemagick-convert, image-conversion

I have a directory called "plots_for_gifs", which contains 105 files, whose names are identical apart from they end in ...000.png, ...001.png ... etc. up to ...104.png. I am trying to convert them to a .gif using:

```
convert -density 150 -trim -delay 35 -loop 0 ./plots_for_gifs/*.png ./river_diff.gif
```

The image files are 491x411 pixels, however the gif produced is 7017x4958 pixels! Even though I am including "-trim", and the same occurs even if I add "-size 491x411"... any ideas?

I am running this in a bash shell in Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmmm.... a couple of things.

You don't need `-density` at all with `PNG` files because it only sets the density to be used when rasterising vector files such as `SVG`. So, you can omit that.

If, as you say, your images are already the correct size, you don't need `-trim`. So, you can omit that too.

You don't need to prefix filenames with `./`, as that just means *"the current directory"* which is the default anyway, so you can omit that.

Now to the actual problem. I guess your PNG files have been cropped from some larger images and have *"remembered"* their previous canvas size. The best way to make them forget, is to use `+repage` after loading them.

So, without seeing your files, I suspect you want something more like:

```
convert -delay 35 -loop 0 plots_for_gifs/*.png +repage river_diff.gif
```

If you find you do need `-trim`, add it into the above command **before** `+repage`.

---

If that doesn't work, please run the following command and paste the output in your original question - by clicking `edit` underneath it:

```
identify plots_for_gifs/*000.png
```

Comment: Many thanks Mark, `+repage` did the trick, the original images were indeed cropped when converting from `.ps` to `.png` files.

Comment: Cool :-) Remember, questions (and answers) are free, so come back if you get stuck.  Good luck with your project!